# can i make map in ROS using rqt?

Tags: gps, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ask this question because rqt is implemented by QT framework and it is the combination of QT and ROS. QT supports to load map so i want to know if rqt supports such feature. if so i want to load map and track gps through rqt. is it possible? please help. . .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70108/can-i-make-map-in-ros-using-rqt-?/) by [Bindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5524/bindu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's `rqt` tool called [rqt_marble](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_marble), on which it's been a while since I've not been able to work. It only can currently publish GPS coordinates of the waypoints between 2 points calculated by `KDE`'s `Marble` library. I have in mind to add subscribing and plotting GPS of multiple robots. Feature idea was discussed [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/41).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on 2013-08-01**:
Also take a look at this answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/57313/geo-referenced-mapping-interface-for-rosrviz/

**Comment by [Bindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5524/bindu/) on 2013-08-01**:
Hi, i am also facing same problem  like here  http://answers.ros.org/question/57313/geo-referenced-mapping-interface-for-rosrviz/   may i know how you got solution at last? or any idea for me? please give your suggestions.   i want to load a map and track gps based on /GPSFix message from lidar. i need to get waypoints also . The main thing is everything should be done without internet connection.

up to my knowledge qt is able to load map online only. is it correct? if so what about rqt?